# Db2 procedures and Python: Why does ibm_db.callproc in some cases return None?

Tags: python, db2

In db2 mini IIAS, wWhen executing a procedure with `ibm_db.callproc`, there is a case where the return value is **None**.
Depending on the procedure, it can be obtained correctly, but sometimes it can not be, why such thing happens?

Please find the below screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

"None" is a Python value and it would mean that in SQL nothing (Null) is returned. [The Python SDK returns `None` for callproc on error](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/wiki/APIs#ibm_dbcallproc). The reason are the semantics of the [Db2 CALL statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000897.html?pos=2). On error, the OUT parameters are not set and INOUT parameters are unchanged.

In conclusion, it seems that the procedure that returns "None" encountered an error.

Comment: thanks for your reply, let me check and get back to you